# Show that any biholomorphic map from the upper half plane to itself is a Mobius transform

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

> Show that any biholomorphic map from $U = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : Im(z)>0\}$ to $U$ is a Mobius transformation.

I know this statement to be true, just having a hard time directly proving this, I think I am confusing myself on how to start. Can someone give me a hint on what to do here or show me how I would go about this?

My fist thought was to characterize all biholomorphic maps from $U$ to $U$ and hope that I see the form of a mobius transformation fall out, from there I would show that the determinant of the coefficients was equal to one, but I wasn't sure how to characterize these maps and even if I could I think I would have a hard time directly showing the determinant of the coefficients was one. I am a first time complex analysis student and my professor has decided to go out of order and kind of out of our textbook to teach conformal mappings and mobius transforms so I am a little confused here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is very easy to do moving to the unit disc (in other words biholomorphisms of the unit disc are Mobius of the appropriate type which is very easy to prove by Schwarz and transitivity) and then a biholomorphism between the unit disc and upper plane is also Mobius, so one gets that biholomorphisms of the upper plane are compositions of Mobius which are also Mobius etc

Comment: @Conrad Ah I see, so consider the mobius transform from unit disk to upper half plane and then another mobius transform from upper half plane to unit disk then the composition is the map we want and is also a mobius transform?

Comment: There is the third map which  is the bilohomorphism of the unit disc induced as above and that is also Mobius - this part is the essence of the proof but it is easy by Schwarz as one uses a mobius disc automorphism to fix zero and then Schwarz implies the map is just a rotation $\alpha z, |\alpha|=1$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, this is clear now! Cheers.

Comment: Happy to be of help